# document.getElementById() gives null when called in onload

Tags: javascript

I have HTML like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
var x=null;
function myFunction()
{
x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<h1 id="myHeader" onclick="getValue()">Click me!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue that I am facing is sometimes the variable x is null after page loading. Any guesses about the cause of this issue.

Comment: We don't really do 'guesses' I'm afraid; if you can find a situation in which the variable `x` is *always* `null`, then we'll be able to help. Though, at that point, you'll probably work out what the problem was.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of "x" using the "getValue()" function you're calling onclick?

Comment: That code is fine, but it does nothing (and will error out if you click the header). Where do you want to use x? It's local to myFunction. And where is getValue?

Comment: As @bfavaretto says, it's local to myFunction. If you want to export this variable, try `window.x = document.getElementById("myHeader");`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var x=document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML;
```

This will get the text for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having issues with the DOM not being loaded all the way before your function is called.

Try moving the script definition to the bottom of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <h1 id="myHeader" onclick="getValue()">Click me!</h1>
    <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
            var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some issues in your script :

1) getValue function is not defined, You have to define getVal.

2) You have to use return(x) in the myFunction().

```
<script>
   myFunction = function(){
      var x = document.getElementById('myId');
      return(x);
   }
   // now whenever you call myFunction it will return you the object 'myId'
</script>
```

3) Or create a golobal varriable X in the document (out of myFunction) so you can call it from evrywhere.

```
<script>
    var x; // this will be a global variable
    myFunction = function(){
       x = document.getElementById('myId');
    }
</script>
```